# src() function in CSS, semantic alternative to url()

Tags: html, css, url, src

The [MDN documentation describes `url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url) function which can include external file into CSS. This gives an ability to use arbitrary URLs as background images or just as images.

The [CSS Values specification for `url()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#urls) explains that there are legacy parsing issues which prevent using other functions to specify its value: see paragraph right above [EXAMPLE 15](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#example-a2ee15a6).

That example also shows how to use `src()` function, which does not have those legacy parsing issues, so functions like `var()` and `attr()` can be used within it.

I did not find any mention of `src()` in MDN, and was not able to [make it work in Firefox and Chromium](https://codepen.io/abetaev/pen/gOZMQVM).

This function is present in spec since [November 11, 2020](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/WD-css-values-4-20201111/#urls).

Is this function something new that is not yet implemented in browsers?
Are there any resources where I can research roadmap on its implementation?

Googling leads to other `src` terms not related to `url()` function. Please help me to understand.

Comment: Looks like no one has implemented it yet.